# Unable to start auditd

Tags: linux, centos, selinux, audit

I am on CentOS 5.8 final

I recently installed `auditd` via `yum install audit` however I am unable to start it.

I edited the configuration file to give a verbose output of the error it is recieving in starting up and this is the output:

```
# service auditd start
Starting auditd: Config file /etc/audit/auditd.conf opened for parsing
log_file_parser called with: /var/log/audit/audit.log
log_format_parser called with: RAW
log_group_parser called with: root
priority_boost_parser called with: 4
flush_parser called with: INCREMENTAL
freq_parser called with: 20
num_logs_parser called with: 4
qos_parser called with: lossy
dispatch_parser called with: /sbin/audispd
name_format_parser called with: NONE
max_log_size_parser called with: 5
max_log_size_action_parser called with: ROTATE
space_left_parser called with: 75
space_action_parser called with: SYSLOG
action_mail_acct_parser called with: root
admin_space_left_parser called with: 50
admin_space_left_action_parser called with: SUSPEND
disk_full_action_parser called with: SUSPEND
disk_error_action_parser called with: SUSPEND
tcp_listen_queue_parser called with: 5
tcp_max_per_addr_parser called with: 1
tcp_client_max_idle_parser called with: 0
enable_krb5_parser called with: no
GSSAPI support is not enabled, ignoring value at line 30
krb5_principal_parser called with: auditd
GSSAPI support is not enabled, ignoring value at line 31
Started dispatcher: /sbin/audispd pid: 3097
type=DAEMON_START msg=audit(1339336882.187:9205): auditd start, ver=1.8 format=raw kernel=2.6.32-042stab056.8 auid=4294967295 pid=3095 res=success
config_manager init complete
Error setting audit daemon pid (Connection refused)
type=DAEMON_ABORT msg=audit(1339336882.189:9206): auditd error halt, auid=4294967295 pid=3095 res=failed
Unable to set audit pid, exiting
The audit daemon is exiting.
Error setting audit daemon pid (Connection refused)
                                                           [FAILED]
```

The only information I can find online is that this may be due to SELinux, however SELinux is giving me problems of it's own. No matter what I do it appears to be disabled (I want to enable it). The configuration is set to `enforced` and the server has been rebooted many a time however `sestatus` still returns `SELinux status: disabled`.

Can anyone shine some light on this problem?

**EDIT:** I don't know if it is related but I noticed the following message appearing in my `/var/log/messages`

```
Jun 10 16:25:22 s1 iscsid: iSCSI logger with pid=2056 started!
Jun 10 16:25:22 s1 iscsid: Missing or Invalid version from /sys/module/scsi_transport_iscsi/version. Make sure a up to date scsi_transport_iscsi module is loaded and a up todate version of iscsid is running. Exiting...
```

I try to start the iSCSI daemon myself (I have not a clue what it does; I am a linux newbie) and I get the following error:

```
Starting iSCSI daemon: FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab056.8/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab056.8/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab056.8/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab056.8/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab056.8/modules.dep: No such file or directory
                                                           [FAILED]
```

If I go to `/lib/modules/` I notice the directory exists but is completely empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears the kernel I am using `2.6.32-042stab056.8 SMP` which comes packaged with OpenVZ does not support auditd.

Answer (score 1):

```
Error setting audit daemon pid (Connection refused)
```

Looks like it is unable to write the pid file (usually in /var/run).  Make sure that the daemon has permissions to write to that directory to write the pid file.

Comment: Thanks, there is no auditd folder in `/var/run` and I am wary of editing the permissions of the `/var/run` folder as google assures me they are set for a good reason. Shouldn't it be running as `root`?